# What's the proper nokogiri xpath to get a range of rows?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a table with the following format:

```
<tr class="style6"><td>SomeStuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr class="style6"><td>SomeStuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
<tr><td>Some other stuff</td></tr>
```

I want a block of rows (starting with the `style6` class to the last row before the next `style6` occurrence) broken into groups that I can iterate over. Is there a way of segmenting this into blocks? I'm aware of the Xpath `position` function but not sure that it makes sense in this context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

A useful pattern is to count the `<tr class="style6"><td>SomeStuff</td></tr>` that come before.

For the first group in your example, it would be:

`//tr[not(@class="style6")][count(preceding-sibling::tr[@class="style6"])=1]`

For the 2nd group:

`//tr[not(@class="style6")][count(preceding-sibling::tr[@class="style6"])=2]`

etc.

I don't use nokogiri so here's an example using Python and `lxml`:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring('''<tr class="style6"><td>SomeStuff</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>
... <tr class="style6"><td>SomeStuff</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>
... <tr class="style6"><td>SomeStuff</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>''')

>>> pprint(list(lxml.html.tostring(row)
...            for row in doc.xpath('''
...                 //tr[not(@class="style6")]
...                     [count(preceding-sibling::tr[@class="style6"])=1]''')))
[b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 1</td></tr>\n']
>>> pprint(list(lxml.html.tostring(row)
...            for row in doc.xpath('''
...                 //tr[not(@class="style6")]
...                     [count(preceding-sibling::tr[@class="style6"])=2]''')))
[b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 2</td></tr>\n']
>>> pprint(list(lxml.html.tostring(row)
...            for row in doc.xpath('''
...                 //tr[not(@class="style6")]
...                     [count(preceding-sibling::tr[@class="style6"])=3]''')))
[b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>\n',
 b'<tr><td>Some other stuff group 3</td></tr>']
>>>
```